# ¿Como cambio el idioma de bspwm?

Tags: terminal, archlinux

Hace un tiempo que llevo usando Arch-Linux como distro para mi pc, hace una semana me decidí por dejar de usar kde-plasma y decidí borrar todo e instalar en limpio bspwm junto a la polybar para usar mi pc que no es de tan altos recursos. La cuestión es que ya logré hacer que todo funcione y configuré todo a mi gusto, mi problema es que aunque tengo todo configurado en español, idioma, teclado, etc. Al entrar a Bspwm la distribución de mi teclado queda en ingles y aunque al ejecutar comandos en la consola la respuesta me la da en español, los comandos que se ejecutan para la polybar si se muestran en ingles.
El problema del teclado conseguí solucionarlo, pero el de la polybar no.
¿Alguien sabe como puedo cambiar esto y hacer que los comandos de la polybar que supongo dependen de Bspwm cambien a español?
[Imagen del escritorio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMXua.png)

El problema de la distribución del teclado lo conseguí solucionar con el comando setxkbmap latam, pero aún continua en inglés la terminal que usa mi polybar.
[image: Imagen de que la terminal está en español, pero el comando de la Polybar no]

Answer (score 1):

Por si alguien le salta esto intentando cambiar el idioma del teclado, inserten esta linea
'setxkbmap -layout es', (sin las comillas)
en el archivo .config/bspwm/bspwmrc y ejecuta el comando source bspwmrc

Comment: Esto cambia el idioma del teclado o de la app?? porque estan preguntando como cambiar la app....

Comment: @gbianchi realmente esto hace referencia al teclado, no a la app

Comment: Gracias, funcionó perfecto!!!!!